# Way to temporarily disable badge notifications while using iPhone?

Tags: ios, notifications, do-not-disturb

I thought the Do Not Disturb does this, but apparently it only disables calls and notifications when then the phone is locked.

I like playing rhythm games on my phone and idk why everyone suddenly wants to text me when I play, but it disrupts my game play :(. Is there a way to disable it temporarily? I know how to disable it through settings but I don't want to do that every single time I want to play.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Settings -> Do Not Disturb, you can select to have Do Not Disturb work Always, even when the phone is not locked.

[image]